# About MicrophoneSteram.js error on Google speech API

Tags: javascript, google-api, microphone, google-speech-api, google-home

Hello i want to make a customized api on Google Home.

The way it's going is speech-to-text(stt) -> Natural Language Processing(NLP) -> Control my smart-light using IP, port.

So, i'm testing MicrophoneStream.js. but, i got an error.

```
**Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.
sox has exited with error code 1.
Enable debugging with the environment variable DEBUG=record.**
```

Below, it is code about MicrophoneStream.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Note: Correct microphone settings is required: check enclosed link, and make
 * sure the following conditions are met:
 * 1. SoX must be installed and available in your $PATH- it can be found here:
 * http://sox.sourceforge.net/
 * 2. Microphone must be working
 * 3. Encoding, sampleRateHertz, and # of channels must match header of audio file you're
 * recording to.
 * 4. Get Node-Record-lpcm16 https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16
 * More Info: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize
 */

// const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
// const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
// const languageCode = 'en-US';

function microphoneStream(encoding, sampleRateHertz, languageCode) {
  // [START micStreamRecognize]

  // Node-Record-lpcm16
  const recorder = require('node-record-lpcm16');

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

  const config = {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode,
  };

  const request = {
    config,
    interimResults: false, //Get interim results from stream
  };

  // Creates a client
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

  // Create a recognize stream
  const recognizeStream = client
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', data =>
      process.stdout.write(
        data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
          ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
          : '\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n'
      )
    );

  // Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
  recorder
    .record({
      sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
      threshold: 0, //silence threshold
      recordProgram: 'rec', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
      silence: '5.0', //seconds of silence before ending
    })
    .stream()
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(recognizeStream);

  console.log('Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.');
  // [END micStreamRecognize]
}

require('yargs')
  .demand(1)
  .command(
    'micStreamRecognize',
    'Streams audio input from microphone, translates to text',
    {},
    opts =>
      microphoneStream(opts.encoding, opts.sampleRateHertz, opts.languageCode)
  )
  .options({
    encoding: {
      alias: 'e',
      default: 'LINEAR16',
      global: true,
      requiresArg: true,
      type: 'string',
    },
    sampleRateHertz: {
      alias: 'r',
      default: 16000,
      global: true,
      requiresArg: true,
      type: 'number',
    },
    languageCode: {
      alias: 'l',
      default: 'en-US',
      global: true,
      requiresArg: true,
      type: 'string',
    },
  })
  .example('node $0 micStreamRecognize')
  .wrap(120)
  .recommendCommands()
  .epilogue('For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs')
  .help()
  .strict().argv;
```

Below it is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "@google-cloud/speech",
  "description": "Cloud Speech Client Library for Node.js",
  "version": "4.1.1",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "repository": "googleapis/nodejs-speech",
  "main": "./build/src/index.js",
  "files": [
    "build/protos",
    "build/src",
    "AUTHORS",
    "LICENSE"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "google apis client",
    "google api client",
    "google apis",
    "google api",
    "google",
    "google cloud platform",
    "google cloud",
    "cloud",
    "google speech",
    "speech",
    "Google Cloud Speech API"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "docs": "jsdoc -c .jsdoc.js",
    "lint": "gts check",
    "samples-test": "cd samples/ && npm link ../ && npm test && cd ../",
    "system-test": "c8 mocha build/system-test/*.js --timeout 600000",
    "test": "c8 mocha build/test/*.js",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "docs-test": "linkinator docs",
    "predocs-test": "npm run docs",
    "compile": "tsc -p . && cp system-test/*.js build/system-test/ && cp -r protos build/",
    "prepare": "npm run compile",
    "pretest": "npm run compile",
    "prelint": "cd samples; npm link ../; npm install",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "precompile": "gts clean",
    "api-extractor": "api-extractor run --local",
    "api-documenter": "api-documenter yaml --input-folder=temp"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/common": "^3.0.0",
    "google-gax": "^2.1.0",
    "protobufjs": "^6.8.6",
    "pumpify": "^2.0.0",
    "stream-events": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/pumpify": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^9.0.0",
    "c8": "^7.0.0",
    "codecov": "^3.0.2",
    "gts": "^2.0.0",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.5",
    "jsdoc-fresh": "^1.0.1",
    "jsdoc-region-tag": "^1.0.2",
    "linkinator": "^2.0.0",
    "mocha": "^8.0.0",
    "null-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "pack-n-play": "^1.0.0-2",
    "sinon": "^9.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "@microsoft/api-documenter": "^7.8.10",
    "@microsoft/api-extractor": "^7.8.10"
  }
}
```

I need your help, experts. Please.